# How can I reference a training course from another LMS?

Tags: scorm

I've been asked to make a course that is available in one cloud-based learning management system (brightspace) available in other learning management systems.  The intent is that someone would open the course in the third party learning management system (LMS), like Moodle, and then from what I've read, an iframe would load that would contain the course as hosted by the original LMS (Brightspace).

I've been researching this all day and I haven't made any headway.  It seems like there is oauth between the LMS' but I can't work it out.

How can I create a SCORM package that will contain an iframe to a central LMS?  And, is there any standardised LMS/SCORM protocol that handles authentication or something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding a SCORM package inside another SCORM package is not the way to go. The solution for this problem as intended by the makers of SCORM would be to export the SCORM package and import it in the third party LMS, because thats what SCORM is all about. However, this is obviously not what you want to achieve.

In general, a SCORM package is simply a packaged website (with a manifest), which requires a JS API to be provided by the embedding LMS. So basically, you can do "anything" inside a SCORM package, e.g. creating an iframe, calling functions in the parent browsing context, open a popup etc., as long as it is not prohibited by web security mechanisms such as the same origin policy.

In theory, if your LMS would serve the content of the package "as is" and without authentication, i.e. you have a deep-link to the start page (think index.html) inside the scorm package (and the LMS would not send protective headers such as X-Frame-Options), you would be generally able to embed this page in any iframe in the web, thus within another SCORM package. The remaining problem would be the same origin policy, which would prevent the package sitting in the child frame from calling the API in the parent frame. There might be some tricks to work around this, e.g. by using a reverse proxy under the same origin that forwards to the other domain, but this will most likely be not practical or prohibited by other mechanisms. *If* you can work around this, you would still have to manually pass-through/forward the API calls from the embedded package up to your LMS's API adapter. Overall, this approach is not really practical/feasible.

In general, the SCORM does not deal with authentication. Please have a look at the IMS Learning Tools Interoperability (LTI) specification for that purpose. It allows to launch a Tool/Content hosted by another party and provides backchannels for e.g. grades.

I think the guys from Rustici Software provide a hosted SCORM RTE that can be launched via LTI, you may want to have a look at that, too...

Comment: So, in the time between posting and reading your answer, I've seen that I do actually want to use LTI and not the SCORM package route.  The courses are available on Brightspace LMS and I'm trying to access the course through this way.  I've also stumbled across https://lti.tools/saltire/tc which I am using to try to set up the link so I can confirm that the course is possible from a third party LMS... but I don't know what the "Message URL" is, or the endpoint to reference within the brightspace LMS itself...

Comment: Seems like you could accept my answer then ;-) The first thing you have to check is if Brightspace can act as an LTI Provider/LTI Tool at all. If yes, you have to check if your embedding LMS can act as an LTI Consumer. If Brightspace LMS allows you to expose resources/courses as LTI tools, it should show you somewhere in the UI the respective Launch URL, which in turn you can use at the consumer side to launch this tool. Additionally, you will need a shared secret, but this will be shown to you by Brightspace as well, IF they can act as LTI Provider.

Comment: I don't think it can act as an LTI provider :'(.  But I have no idea where to go to confirm this.  I'll email the vendor tomorrow and ask for sure :)

Comment: Rustici does offer 3 products that do pretty much what you describe as being not practical/feasible. Rustici XD, Rustici Dispatch (also available via SCORM Cloud), and Content Controller are all designed to allow launching from a 3rd party LMS while playing in a content serving LMS. It can even work across standards (for instance launch AICC content as SCORM 1.2). See https://rusticisoftware.com/solutions/distribute-elearning/ for more. Assuming the LMSs support LTI, it is a viable solution as well. Contact info@scorm.com for more.

Comment: Can you look at my other question per chance? Thank you for all your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611762/can-i-notify-two-lms-that-a-course-has-been-completed-from-an-lti-tool-provider

Answer (score 0):

### Cross domain fun with SCORM

Another quick work around to "my content is on another domain" is to reference the JS/CSS on the media / content server, but include an index (player or launch) html file on the intended LMS which can bring those in without the cross-domain issues.

So your re-packaged SCO would just have the necessary launch file but inside that instead of the "css/styles.css" you're pointing to "//domain.com/path/to/css/styles.css".  Repeat the same for JavaScript files.

It may be possible the content is a little more complicated than just statically defined assets in a HTML document.  If that is the case it may take some further adjustments.

Wiki here has some extra tips https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki

I'll also update I added a cross domain feature to the SCOBot RTE which utilizes IFRAME postMessage api's to enable cross domain communication from domain A to domain B.  You would have to be able to place the controller on domain B with the content.

GL

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I'm on this case because I was asked to take a look at it as I'm a maintenance programmer/software developer. I don't really know anything about SCORM or even where these packages come from in the first instance (the styles.css etc).  I assume from the "authoring tool".  Is it possible to manually author a SCORM package for deployment?

Comment: Also, I've aksed another question here that I'd love your assistance on if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611762/can-i-notify-two-lms-that-a-course-has-been-completed-from-an-lti-tool-provider

Comment: You can re-package.  Mainly it's a zip with a portable "web site" which includes some DTD/XSD (xml validation) and a imsmanifest.xml describing the content.  I normally don't recommend just right-clicking a folder and zipping since many LMS systems want many of the files in the root of the zip.  I have a SCOBot Packager app on my site w/ 30 day trial if you wanted to check that out. https://cybercussion.com