# Can I notify two LMS' that a course has been completed from an LTI tool provider?

Tags: scorm, lti

Imagine I have two LMS that I want to notify when a course has been completed.  One is the "central repository" of training courses, and the other is a site based learning tool.  They have different LMS systems but they support LTI Providers and can act as LTI consumers.

Would it be possible to have a page on my third party solution that can act as an LTI provider (using a library like this: https://github.com/andyfmiller/LtiLibrary)?  In this solution the LTI tool provider would host a course, and the course would have two iframes in the page, one to notify the site based LMS, the other to notify the central LMS.  Is something like this possible?  If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a quick read of the LTI information it appears you essentially have a few ingredients you'd need to blend in to support communication between two systems.

Appears they use a key/secret and endpoint strategy.  This site seems to have some decent info https://www.edu-apps.org/code.html.

**I am not a LTI expert**.  I've worked heavily with common cartridge, AICC/SCORM and some xAPI.  But, you're obviously in the thick of e-learning standards.

So as I understand the "LMS" relationship to the "Tool" you possibly might only be able to support 1, but I'm not sure if you could tweak it to work with two endpoints.  My suspicion would be since its probably working with something like JWT it may be session based.  Further reading would sort that out.

GL